# Uploading a file in Multipart form data in Qt5

Tags: qt, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying desperately to upload a file to a server in Multipart. I have almost the same code as in the Qt docs, but the file isn't uploading to the server.

Here's what I have in my Debug:

```
---------Uploaded-------------- 3672 of 3672

---------Uploaded-------------- 3672 of 3672 

---------Uploaded-------------- 3672 of 3672 

---------Uploaded-------------- 0 of 0 

----------Finished-------------- 

"Error transferring http://MyUrlHere.com/uploadFile - server replied: Bad Request" 400 QNetworkReplyHttpImpl(0x17589ff0)
```

---

The problem is not coming from the server because when I try uploading a file on it in multipart with a Chrome or Firefox extention it actually works!

Here is my code:

```
     QUrl testUrl("http://MyUrlHere.com/uploadFile ");
     QNetworkRequest request(testUrl);
     QNetworkProxy proxy;

     proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
     proxy.setHostName("proxy");
     proxy.setPort(8080);
     QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

     QString preview_path  = "C:/Users/Desktop/image.jpg";
     QHttpPart previewPathPart;
     previewPathPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"preview_path\""));
     previewPathPart.setBody(preview_path.toLatin1());

     QString preview_name = "image.jpg";

     QHttpPart previewFilePart;
     previewFilePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,    QVariant("image/jpeg"));
     previewFilePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"preview_file\"; filename=\""+ preview_name + "\""));
     QFile *file = new QFile(preview_path);

     file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
     previewFilePart.setBodyDevice(file);
     file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart

     multiPart->append(previewPathPart);
     multiPart->append(previewFilePart);

     QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager= new QNetworkAccessManager;
     reply = networkManager->post(request, multiPart);
     multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply

     connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
              this, SLOT  (uploadDone()));

     connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
              this, SLOT  (uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));

}


void ApkDialog::uploadProgress(qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal) {
    qDebug() << "---------Uploaded--------------" << bytesSent<< "of" <<bytesTotal;
}

void ApkDialog::uploadDone() {
    qDebug() << "----------Finished--------------" << reply->errorString() <<reply->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    qDebug()<<reply;

   // reply->deleteLater();

}
```

Comment: First of all, stop writing in indian style, check everything you do. For example it's not normal to open files without checking success. Then, about your question, in code is everything correct. You must provide API method documentation, if you want help.

Comment: Thank you  @UndeadDragon for you answer. This is the error message I am getting from the serveur:    The multi-part request contained parameter data (excluding uploaded files) that exceeded the limit for maxPostSize set on the associated connector.  I have actually fixed the size to 10Mb (which is very large). And my API is a simple one, requesting only a name and a file. I have tested with PostMan extention of Chrome and it is working perfectly !

Comment: This is definitely not Qt error but something bad with your request. It is hard to answer without API method documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the error. It was a request error. there is a little thing missing in Qt docs.

Here is my code that is working :

```
QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    QHttpPart imagePart;
    //imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("text/plain"));
    imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"version.txt\""));/* version.tkt is the name on my Disk of the file that I want to upload */ 

    QHttpPart textPart;
    textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"name\""));
    textPart.setBody("toto");/* toto is the name I give to my file in the server */

    QString apkLocation = apktextEdit->text();
    QFile *file = new QFile(apkLocation);
    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    imagePart.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart

    multiPart->append(textPart);
    multiPart->append(imagePart);

    QUrl url("http://MyUrl.com");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager= new QNetworkAccessManager;
    reply = networkManager->post(request, multiPart);
    multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply

     connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
              this, SLOT  (uploadDone()));

     connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
              this, SLOT  (uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in `filename=\"version.txt\"` here:

```
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, 
                    QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"version.txt\""));
```

You set file name here:

```
QString apkLocation = apktextEdit->text();
```

And it works fine just with the following line:

```
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, 
                    QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\""));
```

Anyway thanks a lot, it was really heplful!